# Firemonkey TTreeView - Storing object references in TTreeViewItems, TValue

Tags: delphi, treeview, firemonkey

Was trying the same way as for the good old VCL `TTreeNode.` Ok, there is no `TTreeNode` and there is no method to add treenodes to the tree, instead i have to manually create `TTreeViewItem` instances and set it's parent property to a `TTreeView` instance. Now, `TTreeViewItem` has a data property but it's type is `TValue`.

How to handle this type?

I tried the following:

```
type
  TMaster = class(TDevice)
  ...
  end;

  ...
  mstitem := TTreeViewItem.create(self);
  mstitem.parent := TreeView1;
  mstitem.data := TMaster.Create(i, 'master'+ inttostr(i));
  ...

  procedure TForm1.TreeView1Click(Sender: TObject);
  var 
    obj: TObject;        
  begin
    selectednode := TTreeView1.Selected;
    obj := TDevice(selectednode.Data.AsObject); //Invalid typecast
    if obj is TDevice then
      showmessage( TDevice(obj).DevName );
  end;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`TFmxObject.SetData` method is empty virtual stub that has to be overriden in descendant classes. You cannot use `TreeViewItem.Data` the way you use it, because `Data` actually contains `TTreeViewItem.Name` property.

You would have to create your own descendant `TTreeViewItem` class and use it instead of default one

```
  TMyTreeViewItem = class(TTreeViewItem)
  protected
    fData: TValue;
    function GetData: TValue; override;
    procedure SetData(const Value: TValue); override;
  end;

function TMyTreeViewItem.GetData: TValue;
begin
  Result := fData;
end;

procedure TMyTreeViewItem.SetData(const Value: TValue);
begin
  fData := Value;
end;
```

Comment: If you're subclassing TTreeViewItem anyway then I'd recommend adding a property for the specific to the data type being stored.

Comment: "*because `Data` actually contains `TTreeViewItem.Name` property*" - it is actually the `Text` property instead. `TFmxObject` introduces the `Data` property to return/set the `Name`, but `TTreeViewItem` derives from `TTextControl`, which overrides `Data` to return/set the `Text` instead.